# IE 11: Bad scrolling behavior

Tags: ag-grid

The ag-grid seems to have a bad scrolling behavior in IE 11.
We have multiple grids in different Tabs, now when i scroll in one grid (so the data gets reloaded), then switch into another tab, then back the grid-does not show any rows or only a part of it even though the html is correct. As soon as the User then starts scrolling again the Rows are getting rendered.

This is not a problem when there are low number of rows like 50. But with 500 this issue is consistent. Even standard scrolling in the grid shows this strange rendering behavior wehre for a short moment of time no rows are visible. This seems to be kept when switching the Tab.

Note we are using ag-grid with angular2.

Is it possible to improve/fix this rendering issue in IE 11?

Answer (score 0):

After you go back to the tab, try calling `api.refreshRows()` and see if it gets the grid to redraw.

Comment: With this the same happens in Chrome/Firefox so it does not solve the issue.